# Time machine back up - how can I access my documents when my Mac has died?

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine

My Mac has died (it's really old and has some kind of virus and has finally given up the ghost). Luckily I have a time machine backup on an external hard drive.

I really want to save my photos and documents directly to a couple of different hard drives but I'm not planning on buying a new mac.

How can I access my documents from my time machine back up?

My husband has a Mac. Can I restore my documents and photos onto his Mac without affecting his documents etc?

Answer (score 2):

Connect the Time Machine disk to another Mac, then you can browse the backups by clicking on the Time Machine icon in the menu bar, holding ⌥ and clicking Browse Other Backup Disks….

[image: Browse Other Backup Disks…]

Alternatively, you can look for files just using Finder. Open the Time Machine disk in Finder, then open the folder at this path, replacing ‘computername’ with the name of your computer.

```
Backups.backupdb/computername/Latest
```

Comment: @Kelly, I would suggest the Finder option as you will probably be more accustomed to how Finder looks and feels.